# Trying to automate a process of sorting one column, all the way from "D:D" to "ZZ:ZZ"

Tags: excel, vba

In short, I have about five hundred or so columns, all of which to sort alphabetically (with headers). Although this may have an easier solution involving highlighting the entire dataset and doing a custom sort of some sort.... I've taken a stab at writing a script for it. What I have so far is:

```
Sub ColumnSort()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long 
Dim aCell As Range
   i = 0 
Set Rng = Range("D:D")

While i <= 5000

Rng.Offset(0, i).Sort Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
i = i + 1

End

Wend 
End Sub
```

You can probably see my reasoning, but the line `Rng.Offset(0, i).Sort Order1:xlAscending, Header: =xlYes` is giving me an error. Is this the correct syntax to use for this particular problem? Is there a better way to do this?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you would sort columns 1-500 individually:

```
  Dim col As Integer
  Dim r As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Set ws = ActiveSheet

  For col = 1 To 500

    Set r = Cells(1, col).EntireColumn

    With ws
      .Sort.SortFields.Clear
      .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=r, _
          SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
      With ws.Sort
        .SetRange r
        .Apply
      End With
    End With

  Next col
```

There are a lot of other settings you can apply, depending on your data and how you want to handle things (ie does your data have headers).

I can never remember them all -- what I would usually do from here is record a macro with the settings I want and then manually peel them out and add them to the code above.

For example, if you wanted to sort descending, you would have to add `Order:=xlDescending` to the inner `With` clause.